# how to remove the "PRINT" button in dataTable Jquery Plugin?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I  have to remove the print button   that is available in dataTable Jquery plugin.I am using the following format in my code.

http://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/

I  have added two  jquery files:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"    charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And the jquery  code is as follows:

```
$('#myTable').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
   },
    "tableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    }
     } );
```

Please  suggest me where  i have to make changes..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can provide the button collection using the `aButtons`.

```
 $('#example').DataTable( {
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "tableTools": {
        "aButtons": [
            "copy",
            "save"
        ]
    }
} );
```

Now the `copy` and `save` button alone will display. For more info refer this [Link](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/collection.html)

Comment: Thanks..Its working with  "sSwfPath": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" code